# Calculating part time and full time employees

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have three columns in Excel 2010:

1. Name
2. Activity
3. Person_Days

a pattern looks like this:

- John  |  Activity_A  |  2
- John  |  Activity_B  |  10
- John  |  Activity_C  |  5
- Mary  |  Activity_A  |  2
- Mary  |  Activity_D  |  12
- ...

I want to make an extra column that tells me if a person is working 1-30% of the time, 30-60% of the time or 60-100% of the time. Maximum number of person days is 18.
How can I make a formula in Excel which calcultes that?

Comment: The third column, Person_Days, is that days per month, per year, something else? It'll be likely you'll want to look at the NETWORKINGDAYS function

Answer (score 0):

How about try the SUMIF formula?

=SUMIF(A1:A5, "John", C1:C5)

The above would check cells in A1 to A5 for the value "John" and sum the contents of C1 to C5 where the A column value is "John".

Take that and work out your percentage using your 18 person days.  Then just throw in some conditional formatting to show colours for your percentage breaks.

Above would need tweaked to give you exactly what you want but the core idea should work.

SF